# strike a “delicate balance” when communicating the risk of rare side effects alongside the dangers of severe COVID-19

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand the "balance" here. To reach a balance on a scale, you have weight A on one tray and weight B on another when A = B. Now what are A and B here? A = the rist of rare side effects and B = the dangers of severe COVID-19?

> These events illustrate how fiendishly challenging it is to prove that a medical problem following immunization — known as an ‘adverse event’ — was caused by the vaccine itself. Public-health officials must **strike a “delicate balance” when communicating the risk of rare side effects alongside the dangers of severe COVID-19**, says vaccinologist Kathryn Edwards at Vanderbilt University School of Medicine in Nashville, Tennessee.

> Source:  Nature
> [Why is it so hard to investigate the rare side effects of COVID vaccines?](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00880-9)

Comment: Is this about English, or about medical ethics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The balance here is to put the rare side effects of vaccination (with one or other brand of vaccine) in context against the dangers of contracting Covid19 itself - to weigh one up against the other.

That's to say that the medical profession needs to explain the likelihood and consequent results of suffering the side effects of vaccination - possibly one person in a million - against that of contracting the virus and suffering the consequences.

The dangers of serious illness from the virus, long-Covid symptoms and even death are many times greater than those of the side effects. Even so, people are said to be resisting vaccination for fear of the side effects even when the likelihood is minimal and the consequences could be fatal.